# FFvideo -> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, docker, gcc, pip, python-3.6

Running python3.6 container with Docker

Trying **"pip install ffvideo"** and catching **"error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"**

Can't really figure out where thr problem is

This is full error text:

```
Failed building wheel for ffvideo
Running setup.py clean for ffvideo
Failed to build ffvideo
Installing collected packages: ffvideo
Running setup.py install for ffvideo ... error
Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-41uj66w6/ffvideo/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wvqez2vw-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'ffvideo' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/ffvideo
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/ffmpeg -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c ffvideo/ffvideo.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/ffvideo/ffvideo.o
ffvideo/ffvideo.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_7ffvideo_11VideoStream___cinit__’:
ffvideo/ffvideo.c:1581:3: warning: ‘avcodec_alloc_frame’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:3211) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   __pyx_v_self->frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
   ^
ffvideo/ffvideo.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_7ffvideo_11VideoStream_2__init__’:
ffvideo/ffvideo.c:1946:56: error: ‘struct AVStream’ has no member named ‘r_frame_rate’
   __pyx_v_self->framerate = av_q2d(__pyx_v_self->stream->r_frame_rate);
                                                        ^
ffvideo/ffvideo.c:1957:49: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     __pyx_t_8 = (__pyx_v_self->stream->duration == AV_NOPTS_VALUE);
                                                 ^
ffvideo/ffvideo.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_7ffvideo_11VideoStream_8__decode_next_frame’:
ffvideo/ffvideo.c:2704:45: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
       __pyx_t_1 = (__pyx_v_self->packet.pts == AV_NOPTS_VALUE);
                                             ^
ffvideo/ffvideo.c:2771:111: error: ‘struct AVStream’ has no member named ‘r_frame_rate’
   __pyx_v_self->frame->display_picture_number = ((int)av_q2d(av_mul_q(av_mul_q(__pyx_t_6, __pyx_v_self->stream->r_frame_rate), __pyx_v_self->stream->time_base)));
                                                                                                               ^
ffvideo/ffvideo.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_7ffvideo_11VideoStream_12current’:
ffvideo/ffvideo.c:2989:3: warning: ‘avcodec_alloc_frame’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:3211) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   __pyx_v_scaled_frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
   ^
ffvideo/ffvideo.c:3033:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyBuffer_New’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   __pyx_t_2 = PyBuffer_New(__pyx_v_buflen); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 274; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
   ^
ffvideo/ffvideo.c:3033:13: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
   __pyx_t_2 = PyBuffer_New(__pyx_v_buflen); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 274; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
             ^
ffvideo/ffvideo.c:3045:51: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyObject_AsCharBuffer’ from incompatible pointer type
   __pyx_t_3 = PyObject_AsCharBuffer(__pyx_v_data, (&__pyx_v_data_ptr), (&__pyx_v_buflen)); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_3 == -1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 275; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                   ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/python3.6m/Python.h:123:0,
                 from ffvideo/ffvideo.c:4:
/usr/local/include/python3.6m/abstract.h:552:22: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
      PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyObject_AsCharBuffer(PyObject *obj,
                      ^
ffvideo/ffvideo.c:3086:44: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘sws_scale’ from incompatible pointer type
         sws_scale(__pyx_v_img_convert_ctx, __pyx_v_self->frame->data, __pyx_v_self->frame->linesize, 0, __pyx_v_self->height, __pyx_v_scaled_frame->data, __pyx_v_scaled_frame->linesize);
                                            ^
In file included from ffvideo/ffvideo.c:261:0:
/usr/include/libswscale/swscale.h:223:5: note: expected ‘const uint8_t * const*’ but argument is of type ‘uint8_t **’
 int sws_scale(struct SwsContext *c, const uint8_t *const srcSlice[],
     ^
ffvideo/ffvideo.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_7ffvideo_11VideoStream_14get_frame_no’:
ffvideo/ffvideo.c:3243:61: error: ‘struct AVStream’ has no member named ‘r_frame_rate’
   __pyx_v_gpts = av_rescale(__pyx_t_1, (__pyx_v_self->stream->r_frame_rate.den * AV_TIME_BASE), __pyx_v_self->stream->r_frame_rate.num);
                                                             ^
ffvideo/ffvideo.c:3243:117: error: ‘struct AVStream’ has no member named ‘r_frame_rate’
   __pyx_v_gpts = av_rescale(__pyx_t_1, (__pyx_v_self->stream->r_frame_rate.den * AV_TIME_BASE), __pyx_v_self->stream->r_frame_rate.num);
                                                                                                                     ^
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-41uj66w6/ffvideo/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wvqez2vw-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-41uj66w6/ffvideo/
```

This is part of Dockerfile

Installed packages - python-dev python3-dev apt-utils cython libavutil-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: `r_frame_rate` is long gone in Libav, usages should be replaced by `avg_frame_rate`. The package you are trying to install is pretty much outdated and won't run with any recent version of Libav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to hoefling, 
**r_frame_rate** is long gone in Libav, usages should be replaced by **avg_frame_rate**

Answer (score 0):

> First download ffvideo

```
  pip download ffvideo
    tar -xf FFVideo-0.0.13.tar.gz

    cd FFVideo-0.0.13
    python setup.py install
```